# Maximum character length in simple table has changed. Why?

Tags: ssms-2014

I created a simple table yesterday using the code below:

```
create table DepartmentYT (
    Department_ID int,
    Department_Name varchar (255))
```

I then added the data below to it (which fits in the max character length for the Department name above):

```
insert into DepartmentYT

values

(1, 'IT'),
(2, 'Sales')
```

However, when I ran this query today, nothing was returned from the table

```
select * from DepartmentYT
```

So I tried to insert the data back in:

```
insert into DepartmentYT

values

(1, 'IT'),
(2, 'Sales')
```

But I got an error message that said "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated" which I understand occurs when you're trying to insert data that exceeds the max length specified for the data type.

I then ran this code to check the max length for the characters and noticed that the DepartmentName varachar data type now had a max character length of 1 instead of the 255 that I'd specified yesterday.

```
select * from information_schema.columns  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DepartmentYT'
```

COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
Department_ID   int         NULL
Department_Name varchar     1

Does anyone know why this may be?

I could drop the table and re-create it, but I'd like to know why the problem may have occurred and if anyone has experienced something similar / may know why it occurred.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why the max character length changed, but I used this statement to increase the length

```
alter table DepartmentYT alter column Department_Name varchar (255) NULL;
```

then I re-inserted the data (using the statement below) into the table and it worked.

```
insert into DepartmentYT

values

(1, 'IT'),
(2, 'Sales')
```